# SQL find in string a determined amount of times

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

I have a table with a row that I need to search for a string a certain amount of times. An example is the column might contain 'AD, BM, BM, AD' and I need to find 'AD' at least once in the string or sometimes AD must occur twice in the string.

I have this working properly using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, 'AD', 1) != column` or for occurring twice `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, 'AD', 2) != column`.

The problem is I also need some single characters as well so I might have two rows one with 'AD, BM, BM, AD' and another with just 'M'. I need to search for the columns containing only 'M'. So `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, 'M', 1) != column` will return 'AD, BM, BM, AD' as well as 'M'. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this. I'm open to using something completely different as long as it can compare the amount of occurrences. Ideally a LIKE statement with a regex but I can't figure that out. Anyone have any ideas? It would also need to be in the where statement as I'm using DataTables plug-in for jQuery and the searching occurs in the where statement which limits my options a bit. Here's an example setup where I'd like 'M' to only return rows 5 and 7: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af32b/1

Comment: I added the `mysql` based on the DBMS chosen in the SQLFiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for `'M'` you should search for `, M,` inside `concat(', ', replace(stats, ',', ',,'), ',')`:

```
set @s = 'M';
select * from things
where 
  substring_index(concat(', ', replace(stats, ',', ',,'), ','), concat(', ', @s, ','), 1) <> 
  concat(', ', replace(stats, ',', ',,'), ',');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nFrSgvodjWNsjRJ6uvHZJq/4).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | stats |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 5   | thing5 | M     |
| 7   | thing7 | TK, M |
```

You can extend it by changing the 3d argument of `substring_index()` to 2 or 3 if you want to find the rows with at least 2 or 3 occurrences of the search string:

```
set @s = 'BM';
select * from things
where 
  substring_index(concat(', ', replace(stats, ',', ',,'), ','), concat(', ', @s, ','), 2) <> 
  concat(', ', replace(stats, ',', ',,'), ',');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nFrSgvodjWNsjRJ6uvHZJq/5).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | stats          |
| --- | ------ | -------------- |
| 4   | thing4 | AD, BM, BM, AD |
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like [RLIKE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php) for this.

It uses Regular Expressions.
So it has a lot more functionality to search for certain patterns in text, compared to the common `LIKE`

So you could do something like this:

```
SET @code := 'M';
SELECT * 
FROM things 
WHERE stats RLIKE CONCAT('(^| )',@code,'(,|$)')
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=002ec398511a7fd2d8bed53ef083a77b)*

But in this case, a normal `LIKE` could also work.

```
SET @code := 'M';
SELECT * 
FROM things 
WHERE CONCAT(' ',stats,',') LIKE CONCAT('% ',@code,',%')
```

Comment: From testing those all still display the columns with BM in them but also someone may search "M, BM" so I can't just not include them either. I think what I'll end up doing is adding a wild card for single abbreviations like M# in the database and strip it any time it has to be displayed.

Comment: @steaksauce  Looks like I misunderstood. See update.